# How to pass a verbose String using ResponseBody including newline character and tab character

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, string-formatting

I am sending back a very long String as a Http response body as a part of Spring application, and the response String comprises lines of access log of which  each line should have a tab character(\t) as well as a new line character(\n).

Each line is being made like: 

`String.format("%s\t%s\n", accessLog.getIpAddress(), accessLog.getDate())`

Testing the API through Charles proxy, both special character are shown well. However, testing the same using Chrome browser, both \t and \n are by some reason replaced with a space.

Plus, I am sending this lines of access log using Spring `@ResponseBody` annotation. Any problem with this?

Below is Controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping("/get_access_log.do")
@ResponseBody
public String test() throws Exception {
    return result = accessLogBO.extractTest();
}
```

AccessLogBO.java:

```
public String extractTest() throws IOException {

    String inputFile = "C:\\Users\\input.txt";
    String response = "";


    FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String formattedLine = format(line);
        sb.append(formattedLine);
        }
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    return  sb.toString();
}

private String format(String line) {
    AccessLog accessLog = parseAccessLog(line);
    return String.format("%s\t%s\n", accessLog.getIpAddress(), accessLog.getDate());
}
```

Error Case Screenshot: [Error case screenshot from Chrome brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTnCB.jpg)

Any one could help me out of this? Any comments would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If Chrome interprets your output as HTML, then that's expected. Show us your code.

Comment: @JBNizet Since the controller above write its response right into the actual response body part, the content type is text/plain. Btw, the code is inserted. Thanks.

Comment: So, how do you display this error in Chrome? What does the Chrome network console say about the content type? If you look at the response body in the chrome network console, do you see your tabs and line breaks? Any screenshot?

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, sorry. Chrome interprets it as text/html now, as you mentioned.

Comment: @JBNizet In Chrome network console Preview, they are well formatted. \t and \n are displayed well. But not in the actual browser window. they are separated just a space. Screenshot is on the way.

Comment: Configure the RequestMapping annotation to produce text/plain.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok i will try that. Screenshot link(Error case screenshot from Chrome brower) is inserted at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @JBNizet Issue resolved! The response content type was the thing. If you don't mind, please answer the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome interprets the response as HTML, because the content-type is not text/plain.

Setting text/plain as the produced content type in the RequestMapping annotation should fix the problem.